# Autorun of a script containing libraries not imported in the environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I am new to python. I need to configure python script autorun through windows task scheduler and I have a problem.
I have a python (.py) script from jupyter notebook. This script contains the import of libraries (like "import numpy") that are in the conda environment. It performs well in jupyter. But when I try to execute it in the python interpreter (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe) first I get an warning:

```
"This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation"
```

second, after "import numpy" I get an error.

[Here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8487#issuecomment-509640147) I learned that conda do not support python.exe activation.

So, how can i get python.exe with activated environment (pre-installed libraries) for use in windows task scheduler?
Maybe there are other ways to autorun the script?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that i run scripts with the task scheduler in `windows 10`.

1. create a batch file: `*.bat`
2. point the task shceduler to the python file and also the python executable.

If the script contains the import, this will not be a problem as long as you have that particular module installed.

In your case you need to `pip install numpy` to the same version of `python` that you will be running in the task scheduler.

So, for example, if you run version `3.9` from the task scheduler, then you need make sure that numpy is installed for version `3.9`.

I have not used `conda`. I always use `pip` which i know works, but i would expect `conda` to be nearly identical.

In terms of getting python, you can simply go here and download the latest version:  https://www.python.org/